# Subsonic - Filter by XML Column DataType

Tags: subsonic, subsonic3

I have downloaded Subsonic 3.0.0.3 and I have a XML DataType in my MSSQL database.  The property comes back as a string which is fine however how do I create a line of code to filter by contents in that column.

If I try something like `from  x in Table.All() where x.XMLColumn.Contains("test")` it throws an exception because although the property is a string and the above will compile when it turns it into SQL its incorrect for that column type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interesting - I haven't run into querying XML inside of a DB call but I can see how it would be useful. To get you around your issue I would suggest using a SPROC for now or using the Simple Query tool which does a better job of being explicit.
http://subsonicproject.com/docs/Simple_Query_Tool

You can also use CodingHorror which allows you to write your own SQL (parameterized)
http://subsonicproject.com/docs/CodingHorror

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to cast the property value as an object and then call its `ToString()` method. This causes the Subsonic linq provider to explicitly convert the XMLColumn value to `NVARCHAR(MAX)`.

```
from x in Table.All() where ((object)x.XMLColumn).ToString().Contains("test")
```

You need the cast because the Linq provider will ignore `String.ToString()` method calls when translating to SQL. This is kind of a hack, but it does get around the problem.